# Responsibility delegation in class design

Tags: java, oop

I have a situation here, where I wish to validate what would be a better (design) approach.

Say I have a class 'XController' that contains/instantiates a collection of 'XObject' instances. And, I have a client that is responsible to instantiate the XController.

Now, if there is stuff that I wish to do on the instantiated XObjects, which of the following is recommended:

## Approach 1:

```
XController x = new XController(); // do something in the constructor to create XObjects with ids, x1, x2, so on...

x.doStuff(x1); // which does some stuff with the XObject with id 'x1'
```

## Approach 2:

```
XController x = new XController(); // do something in the constructor to create XObjects with ids, x1, x2, so on...

XObject xObj1 = x.getXObject(x1); 
xObj1.doStuff(); // which does some stuff with(in) itself
```

### Note:

- The Controller does not really do anything before/after doStuff().
- Implementation of doStuff() would typically update the state of that object only.

Any references to why one would be better over the other is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is fairly abstract, so one can only make a guess about the intent of your code,.

Those two approaches are close to being the same thing. In both cases, the consuming code is telling x1 to do stuff. **You should go with approach #2** because it appears that the consuming code is the entity that knows it has an x1 and that it wants x1 to do something. There is a principle called **[information expert](http://javaobsession.wordpress.com/grasp/)**; only the code that knows how to do something should be the one doing it.

If you go with approach #1, it would seem that all you're doing is making another class responsible for invoking an object when the consuming code already knows it should be invoked. Indeed, if the consumer knows to invoke x1.DoStuff(), why hand it to something else and ask it to do that very thing?

Having said this, there are a lot of variables missing here: Does the controller always do something before calling DoStuff() on each object? Does the controller do something after DoStuff() is called? Does calling DoStuff() change the state of anything in the controller? Etc...

Until there is more detail, that's the best I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to say without knowing any more specifics.

But the first solution might be better if the calling code does not need to now anything about the XObjects, as they are wrapped byt the XController. This way if needed XObject can be changed without affecting the caller.

If you'd give a more detailed description about what you are trying to code, one could give a better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Though not enough information is provided, just based on the what is presented, the second approach is better than the first one. Because, if you want to perform an operation on an XObject, doing it though an intermediary (XController) is against the principle of OOP (encapsulation etc), and also it unnecessarily makes the code complicated (it scatters a unit of work on multiple locations).

Also, it seems that what you call here as Controller,to be a sort of Repositofy - to which you provide some sort of ID and it provides you with the object. This is yet another reason why performing "stuff" on XObject in XController is probably not a good idea.